# Why am I getting the error: "`WDRT' was not declared in this scope" trying to turn of the WDT on my AVR?

Tags: avr, atmega, watchdog

I am clearing the Watchdog System Reset Flag on my ATMEGA168 after a WDT reset...

[image]

...using the code...

```
MCUSR &= ~_BV(WDRT);
```

...but the compiler complains...

> `WDRT' was not declared in this scope

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo (twice!) in the datasheet.

The relevant bit is called `WDRF` in the header file...

```
#define MCUSR   _SFR_IO8(0x34)
#define PORF    0
#define EXTRF   1
#define BORF    2
#define WDRF    3
```

...which is consistent with the names of the other flags on that register.

The code to clear the Watchdog System Reset Flag should read...

```
MCUSR &= ~_BV(WDRF);
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a typo. The datasheet shows the name of the bit, but the header file does not always match the datasheet. You have to look at the documentation for your compiler and read through your header files to determine how these bits are referenced. The datasheet and header file bit names often do not match.

Comment: True point, but this case really smells like a typo to me. All the bits in the register follow the same naming convention - the reset source followed by the the word `Flag`. Every *other* bit mnemonic similarly follows the same convention - 3 letter source short name followed by the letter `F` (for flag). Even though the Watchdog Timer Reset Flag ends in the word `flag` like the others, the final letter in the mnemonic in the datasheet is inexplicably `T`. Not sure where that `T` could plausibly come from (and the missing `F`) except a typo! :)

Comment: ...the same bit it is also called `WDRF` with the same semantics and description in the datasheets for several other AVR parts.

Comment: After further review you may very well be right. I have no idea why they would use a "T" instead of an "F" to indicate a flag....